# SQL Server Date time to Salesforce Date in Mule

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have a SQL Server Datetime field with value `1962-04-04 00:00:00.0`. This needs to be pushed into Salesforce date field through Mule. I am handling this conversion in the data mapper.

I have tried many possibilities but nothing works. Any pointers would help.

The last one I tried was as below. I thought it should work.

```
output.PersonBirthdate1 = str2date(input.DATE_OF_BIRTH, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ZZZ");
```

But it gives an error:

```
Caused by: [Error: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1962-04-04 00:00:00.0"]
```

Comment: Any specific reason you're passing the time (and timezone / `.ZZZ`)?

Comment: @admdrew the date format in SQL is 1962-04-04 00:00:00.000 So I thought the last three digits corresponds to timezone.

Comment: Right. Do you need the timezone if you're just storing the date? Try taking out `.ZZZ` and `.000`

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.` character? (`"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss ZZZ"`)

Comment: "It is a SQL Server Column" well, technically, it's in `input.DATE_OF_BIRTH`. Can't you massage that data before sending it to `str2date`?

Comment: @admdrew i tried `convert(varchar, DATE_OF_BIRTH, 101) As DATE_OF_BIRTH` to convert the format to MM/dd/yyyy format which is acceptable by Salesforce but now the error is `DateConverter does not support default String to 'Date' conversion``

Comment: Why not convert it in Java instead?

Comment: @admdrew Do Mule data mapper allow to use java in it ? can you give an example please

Comment: No idea `String temp_string = input.DATE_OF_BIRTH`, then do something with `temp_string` - basic Java string manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Bases on the format of the date,it would be:

```
str2date(input.DATE_OF_BIRTH,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
```

Comment: What does `.S` correspond to?

Comment: @Ryan Carter I tried as you have mentioned but got a message. message='Birthdate: value not of required type: 1962-04-04'
 statusCode='INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD'